# How do i place quotes around a variable before passing it to Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a routine where i prompt the user for a value. In this case the city. They will type in for example LA. I store this value in a variable named inputValue.

Now i need to pass a string to crystal reports that uses this input and i want it to look like this

{member.name} = "LA"

```
string inputValue = GetInputValue("Enter value for " + fieldName);
string sqlInput = sqlInput.Substring(0, leftPos - 1) + " + inputValue + " + sqlInput.Substring(rightPos + 2);
```

O thought by using " + inputValue + " would do the trick but it only puts the quotation mark after the input value ex. LA \". What is the proper way to quote this?

Comment: Try + "\"" + inputValue + "\"" +

Answer (score 0):

- " + inputValue + " +

Should be

- inputValue +

Thus making

```
string sqlInput = sqlInput.Substring(0, leftPos - 1)  + inputValue +      
                  sqlInput.Substring(rightPos + 2);
```

Assuming you don't want '"' characters leading and trailing your string.

Then that would be

```
string sqlInput = sqlInput.Substring(0, leftPos - 1)  +"\"" + inputValue + "\"" +      
                  sqlInput.Substring(rightPos + 2);
```